# Inserting a foreign field in django forms

Tags: django, forms

I have a model with the following field :

```
class Dataset(models.Model):
    dataset_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    taxonomy = models.ForeignKey('Organism', blank=True, null=True)
    citation = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    summary = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    contributor = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  # This field type is a guess.
    submitted = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_updated = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey('Users', db_column='author', blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'dataset'
```

and the following form and the view.

```
class DatasetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    dataset_id = forms.CharField(required=True,help_text="dataset_id")
    title = forms.CharField(required=True,help_text="title")
    taxonomy = forms.IntegerField(required=True,help_text="taxanomy id (ingeter)")
    citation = forms.CharField(required=True,help_text="citation")
    summary = forms.CharField(required=True,help_text="summary")
    contributor = forms.CharField(help_text="contributor (separated by comma)")
    submitted = forms.DateField(initial = datetime.now,required=True,help_text="Submitted date")
    last_updated = forms.DateField(initial = datetime.now,required=True,help_text="Last Updated date")
    author = forms.IntegerField(required=True,help_text="Author For now enter an integer")

    class Meta:
        model = Dataset
        fields = ('dataset_id','title','taxonomy','citation','summary','contributor','submitted','last_updated','author')
```

and the view :

```
def add_dataset(request):
context_dict = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    req_dict = request.POST.copy()
    req_dict['taxonomy'] = Organism.objects.filter(taxonomy_id=request.POST['taxonomy'])
    req_dict['author'] = Users.objects.filter(id=request.POST['author'])
    form = DatasetForm(req_dict)
    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/msrb/')
    else:
        print form
        print form.errors
else:
    form = DatasetForm()
context_dict['form'] = form
template = get_template('msrb/add_dataset.html')
context = RequestContext(request,context_dict)
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

and I need to insert in the database.
Now, when I copy the request.POST to a different variable and try to validate the form, then I get field errors for the ForeignKey

Enter a whole number.

However, if I dont copy request.POST, I am not able to validate the form either.

I am not sure how to proceed with it. Any pointers will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

By your Form definition `taxonomy` and `author` are IntergerField. The dict you copied set `QuerySet` as value in your form, which is obvious not a number.

Why did you choose to overwrite the fields in the ModelForm? Do you want to your users to type the `id` of the object instead of using a `select`? Because in that case I would just overwrite the widgets within `Meta`.

```
class DatasetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Dataset
        fields = ('dataset_id','title','taxonomy','citation','summary','contributor','submitted','last_updated','author')
        widgets = {
            'taxonomy': forms.NumberInput,
            'author': forms.NumberInput,
        }
```

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields